# Model returns no data ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im following this tutorial: https://www.devwalks.com/lets-build-instagram-in-rails-part-1/

To create a version of instagram. When I upload an image, add a caption and submit, it will redirect to the index page as expected but the data doesnt seem to have been saved. When I open the rails console and try to get the posts with Posts.first, it returns nil.

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index

    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new 
    end

    def create
        @post =Post.create(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path

    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:image, :caption)
    end

end
```

Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :image, presence: true
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

form:

<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :image %>
  <%= f.input :caption %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

routes:

resources :posts
  root 'posts#index'
```

Appreciate any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems here:

1. `create` will save so you don't need another `@post.save`.
2. `create` returns the new `Post` object, but you have to check if it has been saved successfully or not (via `@post.persisted`, or via `if @post.save`).
3. From 1 & 2, I believe your post was not saved, due to validation on image presence.
4. Now why it's happening? I guess your form has no `multipart/form-data` set that the image file was not submitted at all.

To add that to simple_form ([paperclip README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#edit-and-new-views-with-simple-form)) :

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks James. I added the multipart and added an if condition to see if @post.save is true. Now I get an error when I try to submit. Missing template posts/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.

Comment: <%= simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :image %>
  <%= f.input :caption %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

Comment: You need to read through the tutorial more carefully. If it saves, redirect to posts page, if not, the action should render a view (usually it's the `new` template).

Comment: Thanks James, I added in else condition should the save fail to redirect to a new view. When it fails however, I get this error: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Comment: It's hard to answer your questions for each step, but the error you pasted seems to be that Paperclip couldn't find imagemgaic in default location. I suggest you search that error and see if there're related questions on SO.

Comment: It turns out that ImageMagickError wasn'y installed properly. After alot of googling and updates to macports, I was able to get it working and the db submission works now. Thank you both for your suggestions.